# Rails 3: jquery_tokininput railcast #258 - how to add new entries?

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails-3, railscasts

Hi I've followed ryan bates railscast on the jquery_tokeninput gem and I've gotten everything working on my app except the ability to create new entries. From the show comments it looks like an issue was started and people have been able to figure out a way to do this. https://github.com/loopj/jquery-tokeninput/issues#issue/11

Can someone please help explain what I need to add to get this working?

Comment: You'll have to give us a little more information: Have you tried what has been suggested in the Github issue conversation? And if so, what didn't work for you? Which server–side language are you using? Etc.…

Comment: I'm sorry but I didn't understand what was suggested in the github issue conversation. I was hoping someone perhaps would have some sample code of how they solved the problem.